# How to parse XML with jsoup

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse XML with jsoup, but I can't find any examples on this task.

**My XML document looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
    <tests>
        <test>
            <id>xxx</id>
            <status>xxx</status>
        </test>
        <test>
            <id>xxx</id>
            <status>xxx</status>
        </test>
        ....
    </tests>
</xml>
```

It should be quite straightforward, but my attempt has failed.

**Code:**

```
Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements tests = content.getElementsByTag("tests");
for (Element testElement : tests) {
    System.out.println(testElement.getElementsByTag("test"));
}
```

Comment: Did you read http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document?

Comment: @JavaCake : what have you tried so far? (If you are parsing xml, java is enough- no need for jsoup)

Comment: I have read that, but it does not answer my XML specific question.

Comment: @Jayan, i normally use the buildin XML parser, but it creates messy and fuzzy code (in my opinion), so i would rather try to use this API for once.

Comment: @JavaCake: Please post code that has problem..

Comment: Sorry! I just realised i had forgot to copy that over in my question. I have updated the question!

Comment: Make sure you take a look a JOOX: https://code.google.com/p/joox/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It seems the latest version of Jsoup (1.6.2 - released March 28, 2012) includes some basic support for XML.

```
String html = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"><tests><test><id>xxx</id><status>xxx</status></test><test><id>xxx</id><status>xxx</status></test></tests></xml>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
for (Element e : doc.select("test")) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Give that a shot..

Comment: xom has a problem with unicode characters as data, and not parsing the document. This Jsoup solved my problem.

Comment: can we parse the large files with Jsoup?