# How to store values as variables in iterator, for loop?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, iterator

I'm developing an Android app. I'm using Jsoup to retreive elements from a page. Then, I'm iterating over the collection to get each individual part of it. I'm not sure how to save each instance of an element as a different variable. I think that I can use a for loop for this, but I don't quite understand it. How would I determine the length of how long to select from? How would I use it? I'm retreiving elements from here: http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=201412abc85d49b2b83f907f9e329eaa&mapid=40380. My code is below:

```
public class TestStation extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_station);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String value = intent.getExtras().getString("value");

        Uri my = Uri.parse("http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=201412abc85d49b2b83f907f9e329eaa&mapid="+value);

        String myUrl = my.toString();



Document doc = null;

TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(myUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Elements elem = doc.select("eta"); 
Iterator<Element> iterator = elem.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext())
{ Element div = iterator.next();

    Elements arrT = div.select("arrT");
     Elements prdt = div.select("prdt");
     Elements destNm = div.select("destNm");
    Elements rt = div.select("rt");
    String DestNm = destNm.text();
    String Rt = rt.text();
    tv1.setText(String.valueOf (Rt));
```

I would like to store each instance (there is many) of arrT, pdrt, and destNm as a different variable. How would I go across doing this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generic type list

```
ArrayList<Elements> xx = new ArrayList<Elements>();
```

then in your while loop

```
 xx.add(arrT);
```

Comment: So then would I have to do the same code above, copy & paste but with different variable names?

Comment: Or, I could use a for loop, but how would I implement it?

Comment: I see your URL is XML (rather than HTML). You might want to use the jsoup XML parser (or a different one) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886531/how-to-parse-xml-with-jsoup

Comment: It works fine so far. I might look at that soon, but I want to fix this right now. So for a for loop, how would I implement it?

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<elem.size();i++){` -- assuming Elements implements List in some way

Comment: And then I would do `Elements arrT = iterator.next().select("arrT");`, but how would I add each to the array list?

Comment: Hey, I figured out how to do it, but elem is a list of all the elements, and the size is = to 1, so how can I get the number of <eta> </eta> elements in there? You may have to look at my link that I'm getting the xml from.

Comment: I need to count how many eta elements there are. How can I do that? Can I please have some help?

Answer (score 0):

`Could you make an class with getters and setters for the properties you're interested in, and create an array of that?

EDIT:
To create your class:

```
public class YourClass {

private Element arrt;
...

public void setArrT (String input) {
    arrt = input;
}
public Element getArrt() {
 return arrt;
}
....

}
```

Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer between Unicode and UTF-8

```
try { 
String string = "\u201cGoodbye Athens thanks";
byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
}  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
}
```