# Formatting snippet of HTML jericho, jTidy or JSoup?

Tags: jsoup, jtidy, jericho-html-parser

I want to format/indent snippet of HTML

```
String html = "<div><p>text1</p></div><div><p>text2</p></div>";
```

into this

```
<div>
  <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>text2</p>
</div>
```

I tried jTidy and JSoup however they adjusts my HTML with  and/or  or . I want to have something that would simply format part of my HTML like in example above.

I found jericho and it seems to do what I want, but I would prefer to use jTidy/JSoup.

Is it possible to do what I want with jTidy or JSoup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jSoup can do this:

```
String html = "<div><p>text1</p></div><div><p>text2</p></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
System.out.println(doc.body().children());
```

Output:

```
<div>
 <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div>
 <p>text2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But how can I handle situation when my snippet is part of head? or there are head and body together?

Comment: @Dmytro If you have complete HTML (including `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`) use `Jsoup.parse(html); System.out.println(doc);` Jsoup also has an XML parsing mode, which will ignore HTML requirements, and will parse anything. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9947639/4428462)