# Parse XML Self-Closing Tags with Text

Tags: java, xml, gate

Hey everyone I am trying to parse this part of an XML file I have. The problem I am encountering is that the text contains a lot of self-closing tags. I can't remove those tags because they are providing me with some indexing detail.
How can I get access to the text without all the "Node" tags?

```
<TextWithNodes>
 <Node id="0"/>A TEENAGER <Node
id="11"/>yesterday<Node id="20"/> accused his parents of cruelty
by feeding him a daily diet of chips which sent his weight
ballooning to 22st at the age of l2<Node id="146"/>.<Node
id="147"/>
</TextWithNodes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code using the idea of using XPATH in Java in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49926918/2735286 (credits to @kjhughes):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {

    String text = "<TextWithNodes>\n" +
            " <Node id=\"0\"/>A TEENAGER <Node\n" +
            "id=\"11\"/>yesterday<Node id=\"20\"/> accused his parents of cruelty\n" +
            "by feeding him a daily diet of chips which sent his weight\n" +
            "ballooning to 22st at the age of l2<Node id=\"146\"/>.<Node\n" +
            "id=\"147\"/>\n" +
            "</TextWithNodes>";
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "//TextWithNodes";
    System.out.println(xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.STRING));
}
```

This prints out:

`A TEENAGER yesterday accused his parents of cruelty
by feeding him a daily diet of chips which sent his weight
ballooning to 22st at the age of l2.`

Comment: Thank you as you posted it, I fixed it!

Comment: @Elliott thank you, but credits should be given to kjhughes. His answer should be the accepted one and not mine. I request you to accept kjhughes's answer.

Comment: Accepting this answer is fine.  I'm happy with an assist.  :-)

Comment: @kjhughes I just feel that this is not fair :( towards you. I have already have added +1 on your answer.

Comment: @kjhughes I don't know if you guys can help me further but can I add <Node id="index"/> in the text?

Comment: @Elliott: Please ask a new question for your new requirements.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes Posted!

Answer (score 2):

Although odd, this XML is actually well-formed and can be parsed with normal XML tools.  The `TextWithNodes` element simply has mixed content.

The string-value of the `TextWithNodes` can be obtained via a simple XPath,

```
string(/TextWithNodes)
```

yielding the text you want, without the other markup (self-closing or otherwise):

```
 A TEENAGER yesterday accused his parents of cruelty
by feeding him a daily diet of chips which sent his weight
ballooning to 22st at the age of l2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML parser library, like Jsoup. https://jsoup.org/

A how to is provided in the answer to this question:
[How to parse XML with jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886531/how-to-parse-xml-with-jsoup?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)