# How to parse .trs XML file for text between self-closing tags?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have file as such

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Trans SYSTEM "trans-14.dtd">
<Trans scribe="MSPLAB" audio_filename="Combine001" version="5" version_date="110525">
<Episode>
<Section type="report" startTime="0" endTime="2613.577">
<Turn startTime="0" endTime="308.0620625">
<Sync time="0"/>

<Event desc="music" type="noise" extent="instantaneous"/>

<Sync time="2.746"/>
TARGET_TEXT1
<Sync time="5.982"/>
TARGET_TEXT2

</Turn>
</Section>
</Episode>
</Trans>
```

Is this considered well-formed xml file? I am trying to extract `TARGET_TEXT1` and `TARGET_TEXT2` in Python but I don't understand where these content belong to as it is between self-closing tags. I saw this other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926799/parse-xml-self-closing-tags-with-text) but it is done in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [itertext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext) from `ElementTree`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

data = [text.strip() for node in root.findall('.//Turn') for text in node.itertext() if text.strip()]
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
['TARGET_TEXT1', 'TARGET_TEXT2']
```

**Update:**
If you want dictionary as output try this:

```
data = {float(x.attrib['time']): x.tail.strip() for node in root.findall('.//Turn') for x in node if x.tail.strip()}
#{2.746: 'TARGET_TEXT1', 5.982: 'TARGET_TEXT2'}
```

Comment: Is it possible to associate the `TARGET_TEXT` with the value of attribute `time` in the `Sync` tag? For example output a dict with `{2.746: 'TARGET_TEXT1', 5.982: 'TARGET_TEXT2'}`

Answer (score 0):

an alternative, using xpath via [parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html):

from parsel import Selector

```
#xml is wrapped into a variable called data
selector = Selector(text=data, type="xml")
selector.xpath(".//Turn/text()").re("\w+")
['TARGET_TEXT1', 'TARGET_TEXT2']
```