# How to read the data between these attributes?

Tags: java

How can i read the node name as 1 parameter and the content of all nodes. I want place them in a map Ex.

`private final Map<String, List<String>>` later on.

So far my code but i get null for node value.

```
for (Node node = doc.getFirstChild().getFirstChild(); node != null; node = node.getNextSibling())
        {
            if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("list") || node.getNodeName().isBlank())
            {
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + " -> " + node.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
        }
```

And here's my XML:

```
<list xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd/book.xsd">
    
    <!-- Nicknames -->
    <name>ElectricPlayer</name>
    <name>Necromancer</name>
    <name>Turnip King</name>
    <name>Esquire</name>
    <name>NeophyteBeliever</name>
    <name>Twitch</name>

<particle_death_sentence>What am i doing with my life can you tell me?</particle_death_sentence>
    <particle_death_sentence>You really had to kill me? I'm farming over here</particle_death_sentence>

</list>
```

Comment: You can consider using jsoup library for this job due to the ease of usage and also the code readability. You can refer to the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886531/how-to-parse-xml-with-jsoup

Answer (score 0):

For little XML Strings like what you have posted, I just use the **getBetween()** method provided below. Read the comments in in code:

```
/**
 * Retrieves any string data located between the supplied string leftString
 * argument and the supplied string rightString argument.<br><br>
 * <p>
 * This method will return all instances of a substring located between the
 * supplied Left String and the supplied Right String which may be found
 * within the supplied Input String.<br>
 *
 * @param inputString (String) The string to look for substring(s) in.<br>
 *
 * @param leftString  (String) What may be to the Left side of the substring
 *                    we want within the main input string. Sometimes the
 *                    substring you want may be contained at the very
 *                    beginning of a string and therefore there is no
 *                    Left-String available. In this case you would simply
 *                    pass a Null String ("") to this parameter which
 *                    basically informs the method of this fact. Null can
 *                    not be supplied and will ultimately generate a
 *                    NullPointerException.<br><br>
 *
 * If the leftString is found to be escaped within the inputString then that
 * escape sequence is converted to a "~:L:~" sequence within the
 * inputString. If this new sequence ("~:L:~") is detected within a found
 * substring then it is automatically converted back to it original escaped
 * sequence before it is added to the returned array.<br>
 *
 * @param rightString (String) What may be to the Right side of the
 *                    substring we want within the main input string.
 *                    Sometimes the substring you want may be contained at
 *                    the very end of a string and therefore there is no
 *                    Right-String available. In this case you would simply
 *                    pass a Null String ("") to this parameter which
 *                    basically informs the method of this fact. Null can
 *                    not be supplied and will ultimately generate a
 *                    NullPointerException.<br><br>
 *
 * If the righString is found to be escaped within the inputString then that
 * escape sequence is converted to a "~:R:~" sequence within the
 * inputString. If this new sequence ("~:R:~") is detected within a found
 * substring then it is automatically converted back to it original escaped
 * sequence before it is added to the returned array.<br>
 *
 * @param options     (Optional - Boolean varArgs - 2 Parameters):<pre>
 *
 *      ignoreLetterCase    - Default is false. This option works against the
 *                            string supplied within the leftString parameter
 *                            and the string supplied within the rightString
 *                            parameter. If set to true then letter case is
 *                            ignored when searching for strings supplied in
 *                            these two parameters. If left at default false
 *                            then letter case is not ignored.
 *
 *      trimFound           - Default is true. By default this method will trim
 *                            off leading and trailing white-spaces from found
 *                            sub-string items. General sentences which obviously
 *                            contain spaces will almost always give you a white-
 *                            space within an extracted sub-string. By setting
 *                            this parameter to false, leading and trailing white-
 *                            spaces are not trimmed off before they are placed
 *                            into the returned Array.</pre>
 *
 * @return (List Interface of String [{@code List<String>}]) Returns a List
 *         of all the sub-strings found within the supplied Input String
 *         which are between the supplied Left-String and supplied
 *         Right-String.
 */
public static List<String> getBetween(String inputString, String leftString,
        String rightString, boolean... options) {
    // Return null if nothing was supplied.
    if (inputString.isEmpty() || (leftString.isEmpty() && rightString.isEmpty())) {
        return null;
    }

    // Prepare optional parameters if any supplied.
    // If none supplied then use Defaults...
    boolean ignoreCase = false;      // Default.
    boolean trimFound = true;        // Default.
    if (options.length > 0) {
        if (options.length >= 1) {
            ignoreCase = options[0];
            if (options.length >= 2) {
                trimFound = options[1];
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove any control characters from the
    // supplied string (if they exist).
    String modString = inputString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");

    // Establish a List String Array Object to hold
    // our found substrings between the supplied Left
    // String and supplied Right String.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if (modString.contains("\\" + leftString)) {
        modString = modString.replace("\\" + leftString, "~:L:~");
    }
    if (modString.contains("\\" + rightString)) {
        modString = modString.replace("\\" + rightString, "~:R:~");
    }

    // Use Pattern Matching to locate our possible
    // substrings within the supplied Input String.
    String regEx = java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(leftString) + "{1,}"
            + (!rightString.isEmpty() ? "(.*?)" : "(.*)?")
            + java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(rightString);
    if (ignoreCase) {
        regEx = "(?i)" + regEx;
    }

    java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regEx);
    java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(modString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Add the found substrings into the List.
        String found = matcher.group(1);
        if (trimFound) {
            found = found.trim();
        }
        found = found.replace("~:L:~", "\\" + leftString).replace("~:R:~", "\\" + rightString);
        list.add(found);
    }
    return list;
}
```

To use the above method, you might have code like this:

```
String xml = "<list xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"xsd/book.xsd\">\n"
        + "    \n"
        + "    <!-- Nicknames -->\n"
        + "    <name>ElectricPlayer</name>\n"
        + "    <name>Necromancer</name>\n"
        + "    <name>Turnip King</name>\n"
        + "    <name>Esquire</name>\n"
        + "    <name>NeophyteBeliever</name>\n"
        + "    <name>Twitch</name>\n"
        + "\n"
        + "<particle_death_sentence>What am I doing with my life can you tell me?</particle_death_sentence>\n"
        + "    <particle_death_sentence>You really had to kill me? I'm farming over here</particle_death_sentence>\n"
        + "\n"
        + "</list>";

// Get a list of 'possible' data node tags
List<String> possibleDataNodes = getBetween(xml, "<", ">", false, true);

// Declare a Map to hold the required data.
LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

// Determine data node tags...
for (int i = 0; i < possibleDataNodes.size(); i++) {
    String nodeName = possibleDataNodes.get(i);
    if (i < possibleDataNodes.size() - 1 && possibleDataNodes.get(i + 1).equals("/" + nodeName)) {
        if (!map.containsKey(nodeName)) {
            map.put(nodeName, getBetween(xml, "<" + nodeName + ">", "</" + nodeName + ">"));
        }
    }
}

// DISPLAY THE MAP:
// Get keySet() into Set
Set<String> setOfKeySet = map.keySet();

for (String key : setOfKeySet) {
    // Display the Map Key which is String:
    System.out.printf("%-22s%-31s%n", "Detected Key Name:", key);
    System.out.printf("%-22s%-30s%n", "Values for:", key);
    System.out.println(String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(50, "-")));

    // Display the Map Value which is a List<String>:
    for (String value : map.get(key)) {
        System.out.printf("%22s%-30s%n", "-   ", value);
    }
    System.out.println(String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(80, "=")));
    System.out.println();
}
```

And what you should see displayed within the Console window is:

```
Detected Key Name:    name                           
Values for:           name                          
--------------------------------------------------
                  -   ElectricPlayer                
                  -   Necromancer                   
                  -   Turnip King                   
                  -   Esquire                       
                  -   NeophyteBeliever              
                  -   Twitch                        
================================================================================

Detected Key Name:    particle_death_sentence        
Values for:           particle_death_sentence       
--------------------------------------------------
                  -   What am I doing with my life can you tell me?
                  -   You really had to kill me? I'm farming over here
================================================================================
```